# Match Error with Meteor.callLoginMethod

Tags: exception, meteor, authentication

I'm trying to send my login with :

```
'submit form': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    var loginRequest = {
      username: event.target.loginUsername.value.toLowerCase(),
      password: event.target.loginPassword.value,
    };

    var callback = function(response) {
      Session.set('showLoading', false);
    };

    Session.set('showLoading', true);

    Accounts.callLoginMethod({
      methodArguments: [loginRequest],
      userCallback: callback,
    });
  },
```

But I get an error and I can't figure out what is the thing that create this error :

```
 Exception while invoking method 'login' Error: Match error: Unknown key in field username
     ...
 Sanitized and reported to the client as: Match failed [400]
```

I founded some informations in the web but nothing that really helped me. I think it's generated when I call `Accounts.callLoginMethod`

My form looks like this:

```
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">
      <label for="loginUsername">Username</label>
      <input id="loginUsername" type="text" class="form-control" disabled="{{showLoading}}" required>

      <br>

      <label for="loginPassword">Password</label>
      <input id="loginPassword" type="password" class="form-control" disabled="{{showLoading}}" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>

  {{#if showLoading}}
    {{> loading}}
  {{else}}
    <div class="text-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </div>
  {{/if}}
</form>
```

Someone could help me or know what is creating this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my 2 cents.  `Accounts.callLoginMethod` is technically not a documented API function and in theory could change in any future Meteor release.  Since it's not documented, the errors that it returns are not well defined and could be confusing.

Since you are just doing password authentication, I would recommend you use [`Meteor.loginWithPassword(user, password, [callback])`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-loginWithPassword) instead.  At least this way you have a set of API documentation to fallback on if you get errors such as this (it also returns more specific errors when something goes wrong).

Try switching​ and see if you still receive an error output.  If so the error will be one of the below error messages and you can better debug to see what's going on.

> - “Unrecognized options for login request [400]” if user or password is undefined.
> - “Match failed [400]” if user isn’t an Object or String, or password isn’t a String.
> - “User not found [403]” if the email or username provided in user doesn’t belong to a registered user.
> - “Incorrect password [403]” if the password provided is incorrect.
> - “User has no password set [403]” if user doesn’t have a password.

If you encounter one of the above errors, then do  `console.log(username)` and make sure it is a string or object with the value that you are expecting.

Comment: Again you ! As last time  a very complete and helpful answer thank you ! I'll look on that way

Comment: Could you help me ? I'm trying to convert my last call with your solution so I did `Accounts.loginWithPassword(loginRequest[0], loginRequest[1], callback)`  but I got an error `Accounts.loginWithPassword() is not a function` despite I made the import `import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor'`

Comment: The function is `Meteor.loginWithPassword` not `Accounts.loginWithPassword`.  Also you can't use `loginRequest` as an array because its an object.  Do `loginRequest.username` and `loginRequest.password` instead.